# schema.org/Offer missing price error

Tags: seo, schema.org, google-search-console

I'm using http://schema.org/Offer for a classifieds website pages. Some users submit a price for their selling items but some of them not. When their ad is without price, I skip the `price` and `priceCurrency` fields because it is better than placing empty values for these fields.

But Google Webmaster Tools says:

> Missing: price.

So what to do when a price is not specified by user?

Answer (score 1):

When Google reports this, it’s not an error with your Schema.org markup. Schema.org doesn’t define any required properties.

It just means that Google doesn’t consider this markup for displaying one of their Rich Snippets in search result pages.

You are doing it correctly: If there is no price, omit the price properties.